# What do you do after paper prototyping?

Tags: wireframe, documentation

Lot's of us - UX people. Love to start their work on paper. Either sketching or using sticky notes. What's the next step for you? I usually redraw whole paper prototype in Axure. Making the same thing twice and than going deeper into details (functional, not considering fidelity).

We've created tool in which you can take a picture of paper prototype and make it digital automatically (fully editable wireframe): http://uxpinapp.com

Would it be useful in your design process?

Cheers!

Comment: I feel like you just asked this question as a wrapper around what you really want to do, which is advertise your product. That's not what this site is for. Try asking again without the product reference.

Answer (score 2):

I just wanted to make sure that you are doing a testing on the paper prototype before going to the digital prototype.. as long as I'm not having the privileges to comment on your question, there were no other way to inquire about this phase of the UX process.

Comment: I do. Not as a general rule, but pretty often actually. Testing paper prototypes is great, quick&dirty method of usability testing.

Comment: well in the process that Im taken I used to do a testing on the paper prototype in order to minimize the effort, and time, as fixing the required after a paper prototyping test is much easier that fixing the digital testing results, now once you got the final and a clear results on your paper testing go ahead and do the digital one,, too many time and efforts would be reduced. I advice to add the paper testing to your UX process.